# Getting a “Run-time error '380': Could not set the ListIndex property. Invalid property value.” error when open not editable xls file

Tags: excel

I'm getting a “Run-time error '380': Could not set the ListIndex property. Invalid property value.” error when open an xls file.

I have got this .xls file from a provider. I guess it was made long time ago. **I can't edit its makros for it is protected** and they do not give me a password.

I need its calculator, but I can't make it run on any Windows 10 computer I have. I even tried to install Office 2000 and 2003 - but no success, the same error.

The provider told me to check for the missing fonts - I've done it, but I have all fonts from the list they gave me.

Do you know any other solution I can try?

[image: Error 380]

Comment: Since you dont have the password we cant help without seeing the code, its better if you ask for the provider

Comment: The provider isn't kind enough to give a help :( They swear the file is ok, and that nobody else is not complaining...

Comment: Have you tried in other version 2007, 2010 and 2013

Comment: Yes I've tried in 2007, 2010. And OpenOffice too (it opens with no error, but isn't calculating anything).

Comment: I see the file is created in 2000 year.

Comment: Is removing the protection w/o provider's consent out of the question?

Comment: Good idea... I've tried to remove the protection by this method: http://superuser.com/questions/807926/how-to-bypass-the-vba-project-password-from-excel. I still can't see the VBA code, I'm getting 'Unexpected error'. But I've managed to save a file copy in 'compatibility' mode. Now the error '308' is gone - but another issue occured - in text 'ø, è' is shown instead 'ų, č' etc. Maybe the provider was true and something related with fonts and encoding is missed in our comps?